# Cassandra/Java assistance

Tags: java, html, database, jsp, cassandra

I'm struggling to work out how to grab data from my database and display it in the JSP pages. Currently, the user inputs registration data such as username, password, forename, surname etc then it takes them to their profile page, this is where I'm trying to display the data they entered previously, but can't seem to do it.

I have the user registration details definitely saving to my database, that part works fine. I just can't figure out how/where I should write code to read from the database, I mean, should the code be in the actual JSP form? or create a new Java class?

I've never worked with Java so that would be more confusing I think, is it possible to run the query from the JSP form? I know how to write CQL queries as I can write SELECT, UPDATE queries etc from the Command prompt.

Comment: Provide the code that you tried

Comment: That wouldn't make it any clearer for you, mainly as I have no idea which part of the code to show you. It's a project from uni, we were given a skeleton code, which is easily thousands of lines.

Does the code actually matter? All I'm asking for is an example of HOW to connect to a database via a JSP form. Say you have a database, which has a users details inside it and you want to display these on their profile, how would YOU do it? Java is new to me sorry dude

Answer (score 0):

You can write from JSP itself using `scriptlet`. But its not advisable.

So you can try with servlet. It will help you.